# Unstable car temperature

Tags: temperature, sonata

Note, I haven't gotten my car to the repairs yet cause I finish work around the time my mechanic closes his shop.

Last night, while driving home 3/4 of the way (total of around 15~20 minutes to reach home), I noticed my temperature had reached its peak so I assumed the water is boiling and I stopped my car immediately in case my gasket gets blown or something.

Funny enough, after waiting for 5 minutes, the temperature returns to normal once I start my car again. Started driving and the temperature slowly rises again. Stops for 2 minutes, started the car again with normal temperature. This repeats for 2 more times until I reached home finally.

The radiator fluid is still full. I just want to know the general cause it might've been before I hand my car to my mechanic.

Comment: Water or radiator fluid? Water goes on the windscreen, radiator fluid controls the temps. :P

Comment: Yeah, it's the radiator fluid, I just called it water due to my mother language haha, will correct it in a bit

Comment: Does putting the cabin heater blower on full hot, maximum fan, bring the temperature down?

Comment: Sounds like you need a new water pump or maybe get the radiator cleaned out.

Comment: Or, perhaps, the thermostat failing closed.